# Square of the momentum operator (issue with taking dot product of complex numbers)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, complex-numbers

So the momentum operator in coordinate space is:
$$ \vec{p} = -i\hbar\vec{\nabla}$$
And the hamiltonian for a free particle is:
$$ H = \frac{p^2}{2m}$$
All over the internet I see this written as:
$$ H = \frac{\vec{p}^2}{2m} = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 $$
But it seems like the sign on the RHS is wrong. It seems like it should be:
$$ H = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2$$
Because of the way that the dot product of complex numbers works:
$$ \vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = \sum a_i \overline{b_i} $$
and therefore:
$$ \vec{p}^2 =\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p}= (-i\hbar\nabla)*(+i\hbar\nabla) = -i^2\hbar^2\nabla^2=+\hbar^2\nabla^2$$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The dot product in $H\propto\vec{p}\cdot\vec{p}$ is just an ordinary (Euclidean), 3-vector dot product,

$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b} = a_xb_x + a_yb_y + a_zb_z$$

Each of these multiplications is just regular multiplication of numbers.

You might have been mixing up the Euclidean dot product of 3-vectors with the [Hermitian inner product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html), which *does* involve complex-conjugating the components of one of the vectors. In physics, when this is done, it will often be explicitly indicated, for example $\psi^\dagger\psi$.